# Python context error NameError: name 'context' is not defined

Tags: python

The following is a script that is supposed to access UV info but it fails right away in both Object and Edit modes.  I fist tried using Bl-2.69.8, then 2.69 then 2.68 and it happens the same every time.  I've also tried adding bpy. to the beginning of *context* but the result is the same.

Can anyone clear this up?

[image]

Comment: Should be `bpy.context`, it's probably treating context as a unique val which is not defined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're looking for is [`bpy.context`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_9/bpy.context.html), so the first line should be:

```
obj = bpy.context.active_object
```

It refers to the `bpy` module being imported in the first line.

You can also use this at the beginning of your scripts:

```
import bpy
from bpy import context
```

The entire script should look like this:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

ob = bpy.context.object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

uv_layer = bm.loops.layers.uv.verify()
bm.faces.layers.tex.verify()

for f in bm.faces:
    for l in f.loops:
        luv = l[uv_layer]
        if luv.select:
            luv.uv = l.vert.co.xy

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

Comment: @MarcClintDion `bpy`, not `.bpy`. Dot not preceded by identifier (accessor), or succeeded by number (floating point), is syntax error.